# Story identification - Winnie the Pooh parody with Attack Dragons

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, winnie-the-pooh

Pre-internet (mid 1980's) there was a photocopy of a photocopy doing the rounds, which is how things went viral back then...

It was a parody featuring Winnie the Pooh and Piglet. At one point they are attacked by "Utter Bastard Class Ground Attack Dragons", who came into view with the soundtrack of Ride of the Valkyries.
The only other part I remember is towards the end, where Piglet has been hit/shot and he was "oozing kapok".

I don't know if this was an original someone typed up, or a copy they'd typed from a collection, but Google hasn't turned up anything when searching for "oozing kapok" or "ground attack dragons". It seemed quite amusing at the time and I'd like to see if it still exists.

Comment: [Samizdat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samizdat)!

Comment: This isn't what you're looking for, but something related is "Apocalypse Pooh", a mash-up of Apocalypse Now and Winnie the Pooh, distributed in the mid 80s via VHS trading

Comment: "Apocalypse Pooh" is in the right time frame, and could even have been some kind of inspiration for the story I read - thanks for pointing me towards that!